# Spring JPA cannot map a field with custom setter in a Kotlin data class

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, kotlin

I've got a Kotlin data class with a custom setter.  The Spring JPA framework cannot seem to map the property with the custom setter.  If I remove the custom getter/setter and rename the property to `login` instead of `_login`, everything seems to work fine.  How can I create the property in the Kotlin data class with a custom setter, so that it is recognised in the JPA framework?

User.kt

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jhi_user")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
data class User (

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    var id: Long? = null,

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = Constants.LOGIN_REGEX)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "login", length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    var _login: String? = null,

    @JsonIgnore
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 60, max = 60)
    @Column(name = "password_hash",length = 60)
    var password: String? = null,

    ...

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
    name = "jhi_user_authority",
    joinColumns = arrayOf(JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")),
    inverseJoinColumns = arrayOf(JoinColumn(name = "authority_name", referencedColumnName = "name")))
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @BatchSize(size = 20)
    var authorities: MutableSet<Authority>? = null): AbstractAuditingEntity(), Serializable {

    //Lowercase the login before saving it in database
    var login: String?
        get() = _login
        set(value) {
            _login = StringUtils.lowerCase(value, Locale.ENGLISH)
        }
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [login] on this ManagedType [com.sample.domain.AbstractAuditingEntity]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:569)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.getTypedPath(JpaQueryCreator.java:377)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:300)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:205)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:117)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:54)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:135)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:256)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103)
```

Comment: what do you mean by custom getter/setter?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan the last couple of lines in my code sample set the 'login' variable in lowercase.  I need to use a custom setter to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using custom setters for constructor parameters like this is a bit ugly (but unfortunately the only way I am aware of doing it).

For starters JPA is going to want to register both _login and login as separate columns in your database since neither of them are @Transient. I believe your issue arises here since you have marked the _login property to map to the column "login" whereas the login property has no @Column annotation so it is trying to map to it's default value of "login" which already has the _login property mapped to it.

Therefore I think you probably want to make _login transient and only persist login (I've missed out irrelevant code for brevity and clarity):

```
...

@Transient
var _login: String? = null,

...

@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = Constants.LOGIN_REGEX)
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "login", length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
var login: String?
    get() = _login
    set(value) {
        _login = StringUtils.lowerCase(value, Locale.ENGLISH)
    }
```

If this still doesn't work then I really think it's more hassle than it's worth trying to get this already slightly hacky workaround for using custom setters on constructor properties working with JPA. I would suggest instead to use a @PrePersist/@PreUpdate method to do the lowercasing for you prior to saving it to the database.

Comment: I've had to change the code to use a `field` parameter instead of `_login` in the setter.  All my tests seem to pass now.  What's the difference between using the `field` property and `_login` in the setter?

Comment: @Jerry oh yes sorry I didn't spot that. You should use field parameter in your setters since trying to use _login as you are there will cause a recursive call to the default getter for _login (see here https://medium.com/@agrawalsuneet/backing-field-in-kotlin-bd9c2d5b6da5)